# Can I use range for a list filled with words?

Tags: python

I wanted to make a password guesser in Python, so I thought I could use the method in the code below. I'm new to Python so I don't really know what I'm doing.

In the code, I had a file containing 109538 words from a dictionary read, and now its a list.

For the code to work, the range needs to be set to the list "DictionaryWords", which consists of all the words in the dictionary as a list.

```
#I made this to open file and read it
dictfile = open('c:/ScienceFairDictionaryFolder/wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()


Password = "Cat"

for x in range(0, 109538):
    if x is Password:
        print(x, "Found it!")
    else:
        print("Nope! Not here!")
```

Is it possible, or does range only work for lists consisting of integers?

Comment: Type/paste the code here, kindly don't use screenshots for code.

Comment: `for Password in DctionaryWords:` is what you're looking for. You don't really need range for this one

Comment: " I'm new to Python so I don't really know what I'm doing." I don't think you are doing coding correctly, you may consider figure out what you are doing with tutorials / online courses etc.